# Is there a way in Adobe Illustrator to import a path from a list of points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, illustrator-scripting, anchor-point

I want to be able to take a list of point coordinates created by a script and import them as a path. The list would be just be a text document with the coordinates separated by line breaks. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What scripting language do you use and on what platform are you? On windows its pretty easy to let the script directly dump the points into illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a simple script (extendScript, put in file with jsx rending and drag and drop on illustrator) to do this:

```
#target illustrator

main();

function map(arr, func){ //extendScript has no map
  ret = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   ret.push(func(arr[i]));
  }
  return ret;
}

function main() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument
    var file = File.openDialog('load points', 'points:*.txt', false);

    file.open('r');
    var points = new Array();
    while(! file.eof){
         var line = file.readln();
         var data = map(line.split(/[, ]+/), Number)
         points.push(data);
    }
    newPath = doc.pathItems.add();
    newPath.setEntirePath( points );
}
```

Script prompts for a file with a 2D coordinate per line. Each coordinate value on the line is either comma, or space (or any combination thereof) separated. Feel free to edit to suit your need.

Or you can let your script write the data directly in your script using COM (Component Object Model also commonly referred to as Visual Basic) or OSA (Open Scripting Architecture also commonly referred to as AppleScript) both of which work in a number of host languages (such as python).

Comment: thank you so much for this script! I'd want to use it, but I get an error message: "Error 120: Illegal Argument
Line: 25
--> newPath.setEntirePath( points );" I know, it's an old thread and I am not supposed to ask questions here, yet I have some hope you might answer nonetheless... Thank you Wolfram from Germany

Comment: @woldo321 what does your data look like?